# Take last word in textview

Tags: java, android, split, textview

I tryed to take the last word displayed in a textview but not works with my way. i tryed in this way:

```
String test =  ((TextView)selectedContact).getText().toString().split(" ")[0];
```

But it takes always all words.

Answer (score 2):

```
String a[] = tv.getText().toString().split(" ");
String last_text = a[a.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
String last = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

This will take the substring from the last space to the end of your `String`, which is what you're looking for.